# Control if a html element has a class and pass it to a angular propertiy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a tab pane which controls 4 tabs, I can switch over the tabs with 2 buttons, "previous" and "next", the thing is that I want to disable the buttons on the first and last tabs, how can I do this in the page controller?  What I'm trying is setting ng-disabled to a variable, and running a if to see if the first child of the tab has class active. But its not working

Html tabs code + button

```
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tab-navigation="">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#aba-atributos" role="tab" data-toogle="tab">Atributos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#aba-historico" role="tab" data-toogle="tab">Histórico</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active painel-atributos" id="aba-atributos">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-list menu-etapas-formulario" data-tab-navigation="">
                                        <li class="active">
                                            <a href="#aba-identificacao" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="menu-text">Identificação</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#aba-medidas" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="menu-text">Medidas</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#aba-comercial" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="menu-text">Comercial</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#aba-tributario" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="menu-text">Tributário</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#aba-midias" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="menu-text">Mídias</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#aba-nutricional" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="menu-text">Nutricional</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="aba-identificacao">
                                            <partial:_abaIdentificacao runat="server" ID="_abaIdentificacao" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="aba-medidas">
                                            <partial:_abaMedidas runat="server" ID="_abaMedidas" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="aba-comercial">
                                            <partial:_abaComercial runat="server" ID="_abaComercial" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="aba-tributario">
                                        </div>
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="aba-midias">
                                            <partial:_abaMidias runat="server" ID="_abaMidias" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="aba-nutricional">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                                    <div class="text-center" ng-show="editMode">
                                        <br />
                                        <button type="button" name="voltar" class="btn btn-info btn-voltar" ng-disabled="firstTab">
                                            <i class="icon-backward bigger-110"></i>
                                            <span translate="15.BTN_Voltar">Voltar</span>
                                        </button>
```

My controller code

```
  $scope.firstTab = function () {
            const el = document.getElementById(".menu-etapas-formulario > li:firstChild");
            if (angular.element(el).hasClass('active')) {
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;                     
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like this 
1. in your html element add

```
ng-click="clicked($event)"
```

2. In your controller

   function clicked(event) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $(event.target).attr('your selector');
                 //set a boolean value to your element like $scope.enabled
              }, 0);
       }